# Send two data packets using a link

Tags: php

I am trying to send two different codes to another page using a link. I am stuck with a problem. The method I have tried only works with one bit of information. I am using php. and the link is generated in a while statement from a database query.

```
 echo "<a href='accept-friend-request.php?unique-key-specificstion=" . $row["unique_key"]. "?key=" . $row["user"]. "'>Save</a>";
```

is it posible to send two packets of data to the next page using a link. without any sessions or much more code. The method I have tried works with one but when I add two it just posts whatever is in in between the two brackets.

*My question might not be 100% clear. please message below on ways to improve the question? Also if there is any questions or comments please post them below. I thank you for your time.*

Comment: Change `?key=` to `&key=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wish to send these as part of a query string (i.e. to be retrieved as part of the `$_GET` superglobal), you need to use `?foo=bar&hello=world`. Notice the use of `&`, not multiple `?`:

```
echo '<a href="accept-friend-request.php?unique-key-specificstion='.$row['unique_key'].'&key='.$row['user'].'">Save</a>';
```

Now in turn, `accept-friend-request.php` will receive:

```
$_GET['unique-key-specificstion']; // Value of $row['unique_key']
$_GET['key'];                      // Value of $row['user']
```